# How can I modify a Mac OS X Cocoa Layout Constraint

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout

I have a constraint setup in a Mac OS X project within Interface Builder as follows:

```
H:|-(61)-[webView]
```

I would like to modify that IB constraint from my code.  I am able to add another constraint however then the console complains of a conflict as shown below:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x102112320 H:|-(61)-[WebView:0x10230a1c0]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x102362e90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10063bab0 H:|-(0)-[WebView:0x10230a1c0]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x102362e90 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x102112320 H:|-(61)-[WebView:0x10230a1c0]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x102362e90 )>
```

The Apple documentation at [Apple - Mac OS X - Cocoa Auto Layout Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/constraintFundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH2-SW6) states that "Constraints are mostly immutable ... It’s algorithmically important. It is much more efficient to change the constant than to remove a constraint and add a new one ..."

How can I modify that leading space constraint from my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraints are objects like other objects in IB, so you can create an outlet in your controller (or any other suitable object) and link the constraint to it.

Then, in your code you can change the constant part of the constraint.

You can also programmatically remove the constraint and add another, for the situation where it is not just the constant part you want to modify.